# Using .map() to render Component UI with information from API

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm currently having a problem trying to get UI to render with React. I'm using information I've received from ShopifyAPI and trying to render it to my component. I'm not sure what to do. Do I need to update the state with information returned from my API? Here's my code at the moment.
**ShopifyCatalog.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import styles from '../styles';
import ShopProducts from './ShopProducts'
import { getAllProducts } from '../utils/shopifyHelpers';

export default class ShopCatalog extends Component {
  constructor(...args){
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      allProducts: []
    }
  }

  render() {
    let allProducts
    getAllProducts()
      .then((products) => {
        return allProducts = products
      })
        .then((allProducts) => {
          allProducts.map((product) => {
            <div className='col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2'>
              <Link to={'shop/${product.id}'}>
                <img src={product.images[0].src} />
                <h5>{product.title}</h5>
              </Link>
            </div>
          })
        })

    return (
      <div style={styles.productInfo}>
        {allProducts}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I thought it might have something to do with using promises more extensively, but I'm pretty sure it's because my state isn't updating with the information that I'm grabbing from the API. I appreciate your time, thank you.

EDIT:

I've updated my code now and it looks like this

**ShopCatalog.js Updated**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import styles from '../styles';
import ShopProducts from './ShopProducts'
import { getAllProducts } from '../utils/shopifyHelpers';

export default class ShopCatalog extends Component {
  constructor(...args){
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      allProducts: [],
      listAllProducts: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getAllProducts()
      .then((products) => {
        this.setState({
          allProducts: products
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.productInfo}>
        {this.state.allProducts.map((product) => {
          <h1>{product.title}</h1>
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But it's still not rendering anything from the map of my state. Is it because map is called while there is nothing in the state? How do I work around this so map get's called and returns UI? Thank you.

Comment: You've got some confusing names. Why is there `allProducts` in `then`? You also forgot to return anything in the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your request in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, then update your state. Your render method is returning before your request has completed.

```
export default class ShopCatalog extends Component {
  constructor(...args){
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      allProducts: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const _this = this;
    getAllProducts()
      .then((products) => {
        _this.setState({ allProducts: products });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.productInfo}>
        {this.state.allProducts.map((product) => {
            <div className='col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2'>
              <Link to={'shop/${product.id}'}>
                <img src={product.images[0].src} />
                <h5>{product.title}</h5>
              </Link>
            </div>
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: After some hardwork, I finally got it to work, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume something like this, not sure specifics to your case, just giving idea how this should look like.

```
export default class ShopCatalog extends Component {

state = {
  allProducts: []
}



 getAllProducts = ()  => {
 fetch(...API).then(response => response.json()).then(products => 
this.setState({allProducts: products}));
 }

componentDidMount() {
this.getAllProducts()

}

render() {
      const {allProducts} = this.state;

         return (
           <div>
      {allProducts.map((product,key) => <div key={key}>
    <span>{product.title}</span>
      </div> 

    )}
           </div>
         )
       }
     }
```